# OnClick, display a div with checkbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've this HTML:

```js
$('.form-group-outer > label').find('> input:checkbox, > input:radio').on('click', function() {
    el = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question');
    if(el.length > 0) { el.css('display', 'block'); }
    else {
        $('.sub-question').css('display', 'none');
        $('.sub-question :input[type="radio"], .sub-question :input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-step="1">
    <h3>Question 1:</h3>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_checkbox">I want bananas
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="1" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_checkbox">I want pears
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="2" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_checkbox">I want apples
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="3" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="row sub-question" style="display: none">
            <h3 class="col-12">What color do you want?</h3>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_checkbox">Red
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q1_1[]" value="1" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_checkbox">Green
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q1_1[]" value="1" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_checkbox">Yellow
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q1_1[]" value="1" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the third checkbox, it display a sub level of checkbox.

Problem is when I uncheck the 3rd checkbox, the sub level are not hide.

What's my problem please.

Here's the jsFiddle if needed:
https://jsfiddle.net/a8rwqe9k/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were over complicating it with the `.css()`. There are `show()` and `hide()` functions with jQuery that I've utilized in my answer. If you have any questions, feel free to follow up.

EDIT: The original question grew from the comments. Edits reflect desired changes.

---

```js
$('.form-group-outer > label').find('> input:checkbox, > input:radio').on('click', function() {

    
  var qID = $(this).attr('name').replace("[]", "");
  var sID = qID.concat("_");
  var el = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question');

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.sub-question.' + qID).hide();
    $('input[name^=' + sID + ']').prop('checked', false);
    el.show();
  } else {
    el.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-step="1">
    <h3>Question 1:</h3>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_radio">I want bananas
            <input type="radio" name="q1[]" value="1" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_radio">I want pears
            <input type="radio" name="q1[]" value="2" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_radio">I want apples
            <input type="radio" name="q1[]" value="3" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="row sub-question q1" style="display: none">
            <h3 class="col-12">What color do you want?</h3>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_radio">Red
                    <input type="radio" name="q1_1[]" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_radio">Green
                    <input type="radio" name="q1_2[]" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_radio">Yellow
                    <input type="radio" name="q1_3[]" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div data-step="1">
    <h3>Question 2:</h3>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_checkbox">I want bananas
            <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="1" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_checkbox">I want pears
            <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="2" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
        <label class="container_checkbox">I want apples
            <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="3" class="required">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="row sub-question q2" style="display: none">
            <h3 class="col-12">What color do you want?</h3>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_checkbox">Red
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q2_1[]" value="1" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_checkbox">Green
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q2_2[]" value="1" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="container_checkbox">Yellow
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q2_3[]" value="1" class="required">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note...this does not work as expected because this is not clear checkboxes on close as OP has.

Comment: Ah sorry. Your code missing part if I uncheck third checkbox and check it again the sub-levels are populated from previous entry.

Comment: I also edited to include @daremachine's (excellent) point by including `$('input[name="q1_1[]"]').prop('checked', false);` which will clear the input box when the parent is deselected.

Comment: In your jsFiddle jsfiddle.net/un58pwe1, I think it's doesn't work at all. :)

Comment: There is some more things I need to look into. it's late so i will look after it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to know if the sub-levels are [hiddens or not](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

Your condition should look like

```
if(el.length > 0 && el.is(':hidden')) { ...
```

also I suggest you change `.css('display'` for jQuery [.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/#show) and [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide) methods.

Don't use `.css` for display show/hide like that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it doesn't work:
https://jsfiddle.net/3y2p7gbz/

Comment: @popol what not work? On third checkbox show/hide sub-levels working. What I missing?